# Analysis the correlation between age group and survived rate

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

```
#First, I divide the age group as follow ,  
 # 1. group A: 0-17years  old;
 # 2. group B: 18-35years old 
 # 3. group C: 36-50years old 
 # 4. group D: 51-65years old 
 # 5. group E: above 66 years old 


 #Then I begin to write code extact the CVC data

 Passenger_Age={"PassengerId":titanic["PassengerId"][:],"Age":titanic["Age"][:]}

 Passenger_Age_df = pd.DataFrame(Passenger_Age,columns =["Age","PassengerId"])

Passenger_Survived={"PassengerId":titanic["PassengerId"[:],"Survived":titanic["Survived"][:]}

Passenger_Survived_df = pd.DataFrame(Passenger_Survived,columns = ["Survived","PassengerId"])

 # consider there are some NAN in Age, so wirte the blow cod to drop the Age data

cleaned_Passenger_Age_df = Passenger_Age_df.dropna()
```

About the next step, I would like to merge two dataframe ，"cleaned_Passenger_Age_df" and "Passenger_Survived_df".
After that, use applymap function to convert the age to ABCDE
Then according to that to find survived rate of age groups
my problem is smy idea is clear,but I don't know write the code,could someone help me? THX!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.cut()` to group the age, for example:

```
group_names = ['A','B','C','D','E']
bins = [0,17,35,50,65,1000]
df['Age_Group'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=group_names)
```

More detail :
[pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)

As for calculating survived rate, you can just use *group by*, like:

```
df.groupby(['Age_Group','Survived']).count() /  total_numbers
```